# Save a file to a variable and not to the physical machine

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I want to create a file using `FileStream` and then save that file in a `variable` for further processing. In my code given below i am giving a path `C:/t.doc`, but all i want to do is to save that `t.doc` file in a `variable` without **saving it physically** in the machine.

```
FileStream f = new FileStream("C:/t.doc", FileMode.Create);
```

Comment: though the suggest of memoryStream seems a solution, but what you mean by saving in variable, Filestream F is a variable. What you want is to Read from FileStream to MemoryStream, So create memorystream variable and read f object to it. Then you can do whatever you want, and then you can resave it to Filestream.

Comment: in `FileStream ` i am passing in the output path `C:/t.doc`. I don't want to save the file in an output path.

Comment: FileStream is for reading and/or Writing to File on disk. IF you are neither reading nor writing to disk, then use Stream or MemoryStream instead of this.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `FileStream`, use a different `Stream` class. For example `MemoryStream`.

The abstraction that the `Stream` class provides means that you can substitute different subclasses of `Stream` without needing to change the code that writes to that stream. At least you can do that if your writing code is well-designed and accepts `Stream` objects rather than, say, `FileStream` objects. Even if your writing code assumes the use of `FileStream` it is usually trivial to change it to accept the more general `Stream` instead.